# Sorting a column of a table which is stored as one string with a delimiter separating each field in a txt file using BASH into an array

Tags: bash

As an example, suppose I have a table (4 columns, x rows) that looks like this (imaginary)

```
John Bake   | 123fakestreet | 435-7633 | email1@address.com
------------|---------------|----------|--------------------
Drew Brown  | 456fakestreet | 564-2436 | email2@address.com 
------------|---------------|----------|--------------------
Avery Smith | 789fakestreet | 754-2378 | email3@address.com
```

The information in this table are stored in a text file, using a delimiter `|` to separate each field in this imaginary table.

Information sample:

```
Avery Smith | 789fakestreet | 754-2378 | email3@address.com | Drew Brown | 456fakestreet | 564-2436 | email2@address.com | John Bake| 123fakestreet | 435-7633 | email1@address.com
```

Every 4 fields or every 3 delimiter `|` represents one "row" of this table. Suppose I would like to sort the phone numbers in ascending order, while still having everything (in the imaginary row) still be relevant to each other to then lastly be stored into a file.

I've tried using 2D arrays to store this information, but so far I can't find anything about 2D arrays in bash, and I've tried "simulating" them as a solution I've seen from another stackoverflow post, but the terminal chooses to use the supposedly created arrays as commands.

Another very plausible solution I've tried, and is the one I'm trying to go through with is using `cut`. Using `cut -d '|' -f1-4` allows me to select the first 4 "fields" of this table, so I thought maybe I could use a `for` loop to perhaps store each "field" into a part of an array, hence the aforementioned 2D array approach.

Apologies for the lack of context, but it took a lot of time and effort (10-12 hours to be exact) to reach the "table stored as a string in a file with delimiters to separate fields" part, and I am completely burned out trying a lot of solutions. Thank you for taking the time to read (and potentially) helping me with this. Other approaches are welcome, so long as they fall under BASH

Comment: `Suppose I would like to sort the phone numbers in ascending order` So you want to sort _lines_ on the phone number column? Soooo `sort -t'|' -k3`? `to reach the "table stored as a string in a file with delimiters to separate fields" part` What is producing "the table"?

Comment: Is it necessary for the row delimeter to also be '|' in the text file? It would make things easier if the delimiter after the email address was something different (such as newline). You could then use IFS and a for loop to read each line, and cut -d '|' to read the fields inside the for loop.

Comment: @KamilCuk The table was originally the precursor to this text file, and is now "imaginary", mostly to help in understanding.

Comment: @Adam Row delimiter after the email address is changeable.  so instead of

```Avery Smith | 789fakestreet | 754-2378 | email3@address.com |``` 

defining one row, I can change it to 

```Avery Smith | 789fakestreet | 754-2378 | email3@address.com ;``` 

for example.

Comment: With the column delimiter | and row delimiter ; some code that would read the fields into arrays like you suggested before with cut is: `IFS=';'; declare -a NAME ADDRESS PHONE EMAIL; for row in $(<data.txt); do IFS='|'; read c1 c2 c3 c4 <<< $row; NAME+=("$c1"); ADDRESS+=("$c2"); PHONE+=("$c3"); EMAIL+=("$c4"); done`      then use ${PHONE[1]} to access the second phone number for example. This is not a 2D array though so you would still need to apply any sorting to each array.

Comment: please update the question with what your raw source data looks like; while you may have spent a lot of time *`to reach the "table stored as a string in a file with delimiters to separate fields" part`*, this may be causing more confusion than help (and possibly obfuscating a workable solution)

Comment: if all of the data is on a single line then would it be correct in assuming that once you've got everything sorted that you want to end up with a single line of output?